# Eye to head parenting/rigging

Tags: parent

I have two objects-Head and eyes. I have set up the rigging for head movement and rotation. How to make the eyes move with the head movements. I tried rigging my head bones both to head and eyes. It kinda worked. But the eye lid movements got weird as eyes were also affected now.

Answer (score 1):

Make the eyes bones parented with head bone. Then select the eyes object and set parent to with automatic weights (Ctrl+P). And now if it moves weird you must check that all the rest of the bones are not affecting the eyes in weight paint mode. (sorry for my bad English U_U)